# How different is gRPC's Trailer than the usual headers

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-java

Have read in the [blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/road-to-grpc/) that in HTTP/2 the trailer data is present in HEADER frame, and I am confused what exactly is the difference when we set headers to gRPC response vs setting trailer metadata to it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In gRPC's [protocol definition](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md#responses), trailer metadata is the HEADER frames sent marking the end of an RPC. There is always trailer metadata sent by server even if the call produces an immediate error (e.g., UNIMPLEMENTED), which is *Trailers-Only* .